# How can I prevent a third party library from displaying a MessageBox?

Tags: .net, winapi

I am integrating a third party C-based SDK into my .NET application.  The application will run as a Windows service on a server, so it should not interact with the user in any way.

Unfortunately, in certain error conditions it insists on calling MessageBoxA, presumably to report that something bad has happened.  When this happens, the service stops responding.  I am guessing that it is waiting for someone to press Ok?

It is not possible to have the vendor change their code for me.

Is there a way I can make this call into a no-op so my code can deal with the situation automatically?

EDIT:  It may be important to mention that in my particular case the service would automatically restart if it crashed.  A graceful (as possible) and sudden exit is probably the best resolution for a situation where a MessageBox is displayed in my case.

Comment: It's not a real answer I know, but find a better library/service.  If a library has this type of problem, it's liable to have more.

Comment: I remember an idiot ex-co-worker of mine put in a message box in code that was known to be a service.  I told him to remove it but he still left it in and we had to re-release the software...  was not good.

Comment: No, say it isn't so a MessageBox from a library!!!! Good question

Comment: There are tricks you could do, like spawn a thread that checks for the dialog window and sends a close to it, but the right answer is C. Ross's: find a better SDK.

Comment: @Steven - can you do that reliably when running with no user?  On all OSes?  I am not saying you can't - I am just not sure it is that cut and dried.

Comment: @tim: I completely agree that any such solution is a hack, and therefore brittle.  That's why I'd suggest dumping the SDK, instead.  However, if you have control over the OS and can adequately test it, a hack might be what it takes to get the project done, so I can't rule it out entirely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [Detours from Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/).  It allows you to detour arbitrary Windows API functions.  C/C++ programming is required to make it work though.  You won't need much.

Comment: Wow, did not know you could do that.

Comment: @nobugz You are like a library.  Seriously.

Comment: I have been reading nobugz's answers on here and the MSDN forums, and I am convinced he is Dave Cutler.

Comment: Does anyone have experience in how hard and/or expensive it is to license something like Detours?

Comment: It is available for free without restrictions on its usage.

Comment: You need to write a book (and if you have please point me to it) because you are a wealth of information my friend! I mean I learned how to read hexadecimal dumps from you -insane!

Answer (score 3):

You could use an editor to find the location of this and remove the call from their binary.  But that may or may not be allowable under the usage limitations with the software.  Certainly if you re-distribute it it may cause problems - you should ask the vendor and report it as a defect and suggest that you have a workaround for your own use.

For people used to do this kind of thing (cracking licenses or other reverse engineering) this is pretty straightforward, but the real question is, what happens if it is ignored - does it still continue to work?

Comment: Crashing is ok in this case.  It is far worse for the service to hang like it does.

Comment: Well then, if you know it is ok to stop you can also just exit the process and use some other watchdog to bring it back up when not found running.  I'd avoid that complexity if I could and just see if you can get away with NO-OPing it.  Then of course the legal issue with distribution/use?  If you don't know anyone who has ability, I know someone who used to report to me who loves to reverse engineer binaries.

Comment: There is already a watchdog of a sort - if the program were to crash it would be restarted automatically.  That's why it is so frustrating to me that it hangs! :)  I don't know the legal issues yet either.

Comment: How about having a watchdog that restarts the service when it's unresponsive (but not crashed)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not very easy.  I would think the only way is to write a message hook to trap messages pumped through all the windows message loops on the system.  But I'm not even sure that a service can create a message hook given it does not have access to the default window station under its default credentials (LocalSystem).  So task # one would be to see if that would actually work.

But here is a rough sketch of how I would try to do it outside of a service context and you can see if it applies:

1. Create a windows [**hook**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589(VS.85).aspx) to trap messages from all windows message queues on the system.
2. Trap all WM_CREATE messages, and probe the CREATESTRUCT paramter for messages that may be originating from your third-party library.  You may have to log all the WM_CREATE messages and then analyze the data to see how you can differentiate your library's dialog from any other dialog on the system.  (Many times the "lpszName" member differs between dialog implementations.)
3. if you believe the particular WM_CREATE came from your library, return a "handled" response from your message hook and don't call the next message handler in the chain.

This is all very dicey mind you, but it is the path that seems like it has any chance to me.