# Prevent dll library from calling Message Box

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll

I have a library written with .Net. In certain cases it shows message box, I want to prevent it from calling it, how could I do that? Just like making it running ***silently***.
**Knowing** that I don't have its source code, and I'm trying to attach it to VB.NET project.

Thank you

Comment: ask the one who wrote that dll library for a version without the message box call and/or the source code...

Comment: Really!! how could I do that by code?! haha...

Comment: As a rule external class libraries should not pop message boxes.

Comment: @PhilMurray that is true BUT it is usually part of demo/trial versions of libraries to display such boxes (for example when you have the wrong license key or the trial period is over etc.)

Comment: Which is that rule?... external class can pop up msgbox...

Comment: @Yahia. Good point, but you really should not be suppressing license warnings :-)

Comment: @IWIH. While it can show a messagebox it really shouldn't unless there is a very good reason for it to do so. As in Yahia's example above.

Comment: @PhilMurray I know all of that, but my need is to make it do its job silently... I think that became so clear.

Comment: @Yahia There is many other benefits of that technique, e.g. the confirmation about completing the calculation-process when arriving a cross-road point, I just want it to pass that confirmation without asking the non-programmer user.

Comment: @IWIH This question has been asked already here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179672/how-can-i-prevent-a-third-party-library-from-displaying-a-messagebox The GOOD NEWS is that there is an answer which has marked as the CORRECT solution! good luck my friend.

Comment: @ZafKhan Thank you brother, I read that answer before publish this question, I re-read it, unfortunately, *Detours* is for C++ Win32 only.

Comment: @IWIH not completely true - you could just implement a "watchdog process" in C++ with detours which in turn handles your VB.NET process and does whatever you need to be done in case your .NET dll library displays a message box (like make that call a no-op). The Professional Detours version can handle x64 as well...

Comment: @IWIH I guess what you need is a hook or use subclassing to intercept the system messages and once you have the hook in place then its a case of recognizing the correct message and stopping it/or acknowledging it.  I found this article on subclassing and hooks here http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Vt-8LH-d1R8C&pg=PA384&lpg=PA384&dq=how+to+intercept+message+box+popup&source=bl&ots=RkiILhY4uR&sig=UYMcdVxW6qWNO3S-fqXbDgyO3Ag&hl=en&sa=X&ei=M21-UaHmGYzGPbe9gNgB&ved=0CGMQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20intercept%20message%20box%20popup&f=false NOTE: Its VERY heavy reading!

Comment: @ZafKhan Thank you brother, I really bothered you... I found this article -> [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24066/Intercept-and-Manage-Windows-Originated-by-Third-p) which seems to use the same approach you had mentioned... Thanks alot!

Comment: @IWIH Its no bother, I have some time to kill, also I note the code project article is written in c# and your tags are for VB. Having said that you ought to be able to convert it to VB. And if not you can do so here... http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=e5919ab1-a015-49cf-a8b0-1cd673d92213

Comment: @ZafKhan Thank you very much, I know both C# and VB.NET, I can *translate* each one to the other... Thank you again.